# iOS TTS with phone call interruption

Tags: ios7, text-to-speech, avaudiosession, phone-call, interruption

I have iOS7 application that play some voice commands using Apple TTS engine, I am using this to setup my audio session:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                          withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers
                                error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&err];
```

then play my command.

The problem that I have now is that if my phone receives a phone call my application will continue playing its voice command during the phone call, the expectation is that my application will be paused once I answered the phone call and then resume after the call is done.

Is there any thing that I can do to make sure that the phone call will pause my app?

Answer (score 0):

When a phone call comes in, the `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method should be called in you app delegate. This is where you should pause the audio.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what if my application is already in the background when I received the call? the - `(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method will NOT be called in this case !! (I tried it it did not get called)

Comment: Do you need to play sound when your app is in the background? If you don't you can just pause the audio when the `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` method is called.

Comment: Thank you, I have this scenario, my app in the foreground, a phone call comes, my app is receiving `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and the app become in `UIApplicationStateInactive` state, I dropped the call (i.e. clicked the red button) my app is stays in the `UIApplicationStateInactive` state, I was expecting it will become active.